# Running valgrind on a C++ module hosted on apache

Tags: c++, apache, valgrind

I have a C++ library (sort of server) hosted on Apache server. I want to run valgrind on it. So please guide on me how can I do so.

I have tried below command. Does this looks fine because I can't see valgrind checking my C++ module hosted on apache. Please be noted that all the required module name details are already provided and below command is what i am using to run valgrind while starting apache server.

valgrind --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes --tool=memcheck --log-file=val.log /etc/init.d/httpd24-httpd start

Answer (score 0):

> valgrind --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes --tool=memcheck --log-file=val.log /etc/init.d/httpd24-httpd start

Valgrind must be executed with a binary file to inspect. `httpd24-httpd' here is simply a wrapper which starts Apache in the background mode. That's why the way you start valgrind will show you nothing.

For being able to achieve your task, you should start Apache in a foreground. I am not familiar with Apache well but seems your command line should look smth like this:

```
valgrind --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes --tool=memcheck --log-file=val.log /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
```

Here `/usr/sbin/httpd' is a binary of Apache.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for replying. I tried what you suggested but still it doesn't work. The main issue here is that valgrind is not reaching till the library which I want it to analyze. It is just giving me data of apache's binary.

Comment: @Nishant, try to add `--trace-children=yes` valgrind option.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your replies, i guess now i get my issue resolved by using below a conf file. A slight modification of suggestion from @nebd worked.

valgrind --leak-check=full --tool=memcheck --error-limit=no --log-file=val.log /opt/rh/httpd24/root/usr/sbin/httpd -f httpd.conf -X